# Bootstrap select is-invalid not work in vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, bootstrap-select

apologize before if my English is not good, i have a problem when using bootstrap-select in vue. https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select

```
<select class="selectpicker" v-bind:class="{'is-invalid': error}"></select>
<span class="invalid-feedback"> error </ span>
```

the code above will be displayed as below (inspect element):

```
<div class="dropdown">
<select></select>
</div>
<span class="invalid-feedback"> error </ span>
```

it doesn't work when using vue, because the `is-invalid` appears in `<select>` and the `<select>` is inside the div element `<div class = "dropdown">`

"invalid-feedback" will appear under "is-invalid".

anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide what are you binding .In your case you are binding a class.So make sure to use v-bind:class="{'is-invalid': error}"

Comment: sorry typo, the code already has v-bind:class, i'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

This should work. span with invalid-feedback class should be below the select tags.

```html
<div class="dropdown">
   <select></select>
   <span class="invalid-feedback"> error </ span>
 </div>
```

Comment: <div class="dropdown">
<select></select>
</div>

this code autogenerate from .selectpicker plugins so <span class="invalid-feedback"> error </ span> appear under .dropdown not under <select></select>